# How do i get "First Name" and "Last Name" from sharepoint list using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I got a list in sharepoint and i want to be able to print the fields out from the list. The list contains First Name, Last Name, Title and some other things.

My problem is i dont know how to write the first name and last name out and the other fields in the list? I hope someone can help :) Thanks :)

This is my c# code.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("MySite"))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in "MyPassword".ToCharArray()) 
        passWord.AppendChar(c);


    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("MyAccount", passWord);

    SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");

    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.Load(collListItem);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
    {
        //HERE!!! I want to write first name and last name out! But how?
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It should be a property of your oListItem. What happens when you try to access that? i.e., inside of your foreach do oListItem.FieldName. (Keep in mind, if you named a field one thing, saved the sharepoint list and then changed the name of the field then it will still represent the first name you gave it on the backend.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this MSDN article, as it may be of some help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521580(v=office.14).aspx

Have you tried putting:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",oListItem.columnFirstName.toString(), oListItem.columnLastName.toString());
```

Note: SharePoint writes the first name a column is given on the backend. When you update that name it updates the friendly version (i.e. what you see in the UI) but the original name is still what you'd access it with.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",oListItem.columnFirstName.toString(), oListItem.columnLastName.toString());

I have Tried this but it came up with an error.
Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ListItem does not contain a definition for "columnFirstName"

Comment: You'll have to replace columnFirstName with the actual column name for your list. I'm not sure what that is. In debug mode (put a break point on the new line I gave you). Look through the properties of oListItem. It should contain a list of your column names.

Comment: Sorry :D i am new at sharepoint :D But how can i see what the column name is? :)

Comment: That's ok, we're all new at some point. :) Have you tried the debug and hovering over oListItem to see what it contains? I am fairly sure it will have a list of your column names.

Comment: Thanks alot mate! I found a solution!

I wrote:

Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + oListItem["FirstName"]);

I tried debugging which you suggested and i could see what the column was named :D Thanks :D

Comment: Can i see the column name in sharepoint? I am just curious :)

Comment: You can see the friendly name, but not the name on the backend. You can use SharePoint Designer if you add the list as a datasource to a page and look through the raw code. (Or the datasource browser that comes up.)